# Random measure definition and induced $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to understand the Wikipedia definition of a [Random Measure Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure#As_a_random_element) as a random element. What does it mean for a $\sigma$-algebra to be induced by the image $I_\tilde B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that $\mathbb M$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $I_B$ is measurable for all $B$.